# Overloaded handlers for various configurations retrieved from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, overloading

I have a switch statement that references different configurations based on data pulled from a database. Each iteration of configuration has variations in what needs to be enabled/modified.

I've set up a method that takes the varying arguments for each configuration and does relevant logic, generally changing elements in a control. I've setup 4 overloaded methods varying in their control type.

```
        SchemeConfigurationItems scis = sm.GetSchemeConfiguration(sid, TriState.True);
        foreach (SchemeConfigurationItem sci in scis) {
            // One of solution, other configuration items should be single items rather than grouping such as this.
            switch (sci.ConfigurationTypeID)
            {
                case (int)ConfigurationType.GPDetails:
                     bool mandatory = sci.Mandatory;
                     pnlGP.Visible = true;

                     rfvGPName.Enabled = mandatory;
                     rfvGPPractice.Enabled = mandatory;
                     rfvGPPracticeAddress.Enabled = mandatory;
                     rfvGPPracticePostcode.Enabled = mandatory;

                     tbGPName.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(tbGPName.CssClass, mandatory);
                     tbGPPractice.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(tbGPPractice.CssClass, mandatory);
                     tbGPPracticeAddress.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(tbGPPracticeAddress.CssClass, mandatory);
                     tbGPPracticePostcode.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(tbGPPracticePostcode.CssClass, mandatory);
                     break;

                case (int)ConfigurationType.ReferralOwner:
                     configHandler(sci, ddlOwners, isReferralOwnerConfig, rfvOwners);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.RequiresAssessmentsPassed:
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.ReferralDateReceived:
                     configHandler(sci, tbReferralReceivedDate, isReferralDateReceivedConfig, rfvReferralReceivedDate ,pnlReferralReceivedDate);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.ReasonForReferral:
                     configHandler(sci, tbReason, isReasonForReferralConfig, rfvReason, pnlReason);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.HealthCheck:
                     configHandler(sci, rblHealthCheck, isHealthCheckConfig, rfvHealthCheck, pnlHealthCheck);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.PersonalSafety:
                     configHandler(sci, rblPersonalSafety, isPersonalSafetyConfig, rfvrblPersonalSafety, pnlPersonalSafety);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.PersonalSafetyDetail:
                     configHandler(sci, tbPersonalSafety, isPersonalSafetyDetailConfig, rfvtbPersonalSafety, pnlPersonalSafetyDetail);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.ServiceAwarenessMethod:
                     configHandler(sci, ddlServiceAwarenessMethod, isServiceAwarenessMethodConfig, pnl: pnlServiceAwarenessMethod);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.ActivitySelection:
                     configHandler(sci, cbActivitySelection, isActivitySelectionConfig, pnl: pnlActivitySelection);
                     break;
                case (int)ConfigurationType.StatLog:
                     configHandler(sci: sci, pnl: pnlStatLog, def: "");
                     break;
            }
        }
```

This is a section of the switch statement, there's going to be around 50 more so this is how the general flow goes.

```
    public void configHandler(SchemeConfigurationItem sci = null, DropDownList ddl = null, bool Config = true, RequiredFieldValidator rfv = null, Panel pnl = null, string def = "")
    {
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            pnl.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active);
        }
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active))
        {
            Config = true;

            if (ddl != null)
            {
                ddl.CssClass = sci.CssClass != String.Empty ? sci.CssClass : ddl.CssClass;
                ddl.ToolTip = sci.ToolTip != String.Empty ? sci.ToolTip : ddl.ToolTip;
                ddl.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(ddl.CssClass, rfv.Enabled);
            }

            if (rfv != null)
            {
                rfv.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Mandatory);
                rfv.ErrorMessage = sci.ErrorMessage != String.Empty ? sci.ErrorMessage : rfv.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
    }

    public void configHandler(SchemeConfigurationItem sci = null, TextBox tb = null, bool Config = true, RequiredFieldValidator rfv = null, Panel pnl = null)
    {
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            pnl.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active);
        }
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active))
        {
            Config = true;

            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.CssClass = sci.CssClass != String.Empty ? sci.CssClass : tb.CssClass;
                tb.ToolTip = sci.ToolTip != String.Empty ? sci.ToolTip : tb.ToolTip;
                tb.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(tb.CssClass, rfv.Enabled);
            }

            if (rfv != null)
            {
                rfv.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Mandatory);
                rfv.ErrorMessage = sci.ErrorMessage != String.Empty ? sci.ErrorMessage : rfv.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
    }

    public void configHandler(SchemeConfigurationItem sci = null, RadioButtonList rbl = null, bool Config = true, RequiredFieldValidator rfv = null, Panel pnl = null)
    {
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            pnl.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active);
        }
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active))
        {
            Config = true;

            if (rbl != null)
            {
                rbl.CssClass = sci.CssClass != String.Empty ? sci.CssClass : rbl.CssClass;
                rbl.ToolTip = sci.ToolTip != String.Empty ? sci.ToolTip : rbl.ToolTip;
                rbl.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(rbl.CssClass, rfv.Enabled);
            }

            if (rfv != null)
            {
                rfv.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Mandatory);
                rfv.ErrorMessage = sci.ErrorMessage != String.Empty ? sci.ErrorMessage : rfv.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
    }

    public void configHandler(SchemeConfigurationItem sci = null, CheckBoxList cbl = null, bool Config = true, RequiredFieldValidator rfv = null, Panel pnl = null)
    {
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            pnl.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active);
        }
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active))
        {
            Config = true;

            if (cbl != null)
            {
                cbl.CssClass = sci.CssClass != String.Empty ? sci.CssClass : cbl.CssClass;
                cbl.ToolTip = sci.ToolTip != String.Empty ? sci.ToolTip : cbl.ToolTip;
                cbl.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(cbl.CssClass, rfv.Enabled);
            }

            if (rfv != null)
            {
                rfv.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Mandatory);
                rfv.ErrorMessage = sci.ErrorMessage != String.Empty ? sci.ErrorMessage : rfv.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the overloaded methods, as you can see all of the parameters are optional to allow for varied config. Some of you may notice the `string def = ""` in the first method, I implemented this to target a default method, if the key parameter wasn't included, in this example the Control type.

I'm looking for ways to make the solution neater, cleaner and smaller.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your `configHandler`?

Comment: @Mast The configHandler takes the optional parameters and applies values passed in the sci to the targeted Control and Validator, all of these are optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've fallen pray to the <kbd>Copy</kbd>+<kbd>Paste</kbd> monster.

There *will* be a point where you'll "need" an overload of `configHandler` that the compiler won't be able to resolve; instead of adding bogus parameters and change the order of the parameters (i.e. making the API a nightmare), you need to step back and think of another way.

But first things first. Close your eyes, empty your mind. Breathe.

<sub>Still reading? I said *close your eyes*!</sub>

Okay. Now that your mind is completely cleansed, what does "config handler" evoke?

- CSS classes
- UI controls
- **~> Configuration settings <~**
- Tooltips

Did you say *configuration settings*? There's absolutely no subliminal mind-trickery here: "config handler" invariably rings "configuration settings" in the reader's mind - and this will be you in 6 months, or someone else inheriting the code base to maintain it. But "configuration settings" in any .net dev's mind, points to `web.config`, not *CSS styles*.

A "handler" is usually what we call a method that *handles* an `event`; it has a signature that matches that of some `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate. Using the term "handler" for something that's not a "handler" is *also* confusing.

So "config handler" isn't about *config*, and isn't about *handling* either.

You need a *wildly* different approach: you simply can't keep going like this (*50 overloads?* no thanks!). Assuming your controls are all inherited from the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` class, I'd start by combining all overloads and leveraging the controls' inheritance hierarchy:

```
private void SetControlProperties(SchemeConfigurationItem item, WebControl control, RequiredFieldValidator validator, WebControl panel = null)
{
    if (control == null) { return; }
    if (validator == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("validator"); } // little assumption here...

    if (panel != null)
    {
        panel.Visible = item.IsActive;
    }

    validator.IsEnabled = item.IsMandatory; // why isn't that a bool in the first place?

    validator.ErrorMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ErrorMessage)
        ? validator.ErrorMessage
        : item.ErrorMessage;

    var css = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CssClass)
        ? control.CssClass
        : item.CssClass;

    control.CssClass = ApplyMandatoryFieldStyle(css, validator.IsEnabled); // method could very likely be inlined here

    control.ToolTip = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToolTip)
        ? control.ToolTip
        : item.ToolTip;
}
```

Note, your methods can throw a possible `NullReferenceException` if `rfv` is `null`, because you're reading its `Enabled` property *and then* checking if it's `null` or not. You're also *setting* its `Enabled` property *after* you've read it, which makes your workflow extremely confusing - it's not clear what happens to the `ErrorMessage` either, and the `Config` parameter seems utterly useless; it's assigned a value, and then that value gets lost in limbo.

Another thing - why cast every single `case` to `int`, if you can work with the enum type and cast the `ConfigurationtypeID` you're switching on (once!) instead? That would reduce visual clutter a bit:

```
switch ((ConfigurationType)sci.ConfigurationTypeID)
{
    case ConfigurationType.ReferralOwner:
        SetControlProperties(sci, ddlOwners, rfvOwners);
        break;
    case ConfigurationType.ReferralDateReceived:
        SetControlProperties(sci, tbReferralReceivedDate, rfvReferralReceivedDate, pnlReferralReceivedDate);
        break;
    case ConfigurationType.ReasonForReferral:
        SetControlProperties(sci, tbReason, rfvReason, pnlReason);
        break;
    case ConfigurationType.HealthCheck:
        SetControlProperties(sci, rblHealthCheck, rfvHealthCheck, pnlHealthCheck);
        break;
    //...
}
```

Now, that's *a little better*... but I'd warmly recommend you consider implementing validation [using the tools the framework is giving you](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation); validation is a solved problem, no need to implement your own framework for it - that `switch` block smells like you're working at a much lower level of abstraction than that of the tools the framework is putting in your hands. You probably don't need that `switch` block at all.

Comment: Great answer, I'll be marking this as the accepted choice due to its simplicity, and neat style. I've taken on board the suggestions you've made and it looks great!

With regards to the switch block, it's not for applying validation, we have a large page that varies based on data extracted from a database, each client essentially has their own configuration and these individual items are a list of possible variations that need to be toggled on a per client basis. The variations in validation are simply to allow us to implement custom values without changing the hard code.

Answer (score 3):

- The `SchemeConfigurationItem sci = null` parameter doesn't need to be optional because you are always passing a parameter which can't be `null`.
- Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) for .NET methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing.
- You have the following in each of the overloaded methods

  ```
  if (rfv != null)
  {
      rfv.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Mandatory);
      rfv.ErrorMessage = sci.ErrorMessage != String.Empty ? sci.ErrorMessage : rfv.ErrorMessage;
  }
  ```

  This should be extracted to a separate method to remove code duplication. It is easier to change something in one place instead of changing it in multiple places and maybe forget one.
- You should really work on the naming of things. Its a hard task to find good and descriptive names but it will save  a lot of time afterwards if you or **Sam the maintainer** will have to fix a bug. Names like `sci` or `pnlGP` won't tell you what it is about.
- If you invert the condition

  ```
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active))
  ```

  you can return early and save one level of indentation which makes the code easier to read like so

  ```
  if (!Convert.ToBoolean(sci.Active))  
  {
      return;
  }
  ```

Comment: Why does indentation make it harder to read? I agree with your point, I actually prefer your example, I'm just curious as to why?

Comment: @S.Wessels the more visual noise, the heavier the cognitive load. It reduces the *signal-to-noise* ratio.

Comment: What @Mat'sMug said and because you need to scroll if the indentation is going to be very deep. Its just a pointer to use early returns if possible.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any reference to more I can read up on? or is this personal experience?

Comment: One way would be to read just the [tag:c#] tagged questions here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

All your `configHandler` methods differ only by one parameter and they are all amost identical. You also use the same properties for each control (second parameter).

You should create an interface for it

```
public interface IStyleable
{
    string CssClass { get; set; }
    string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

that you will pass to a single `configHandler` via a `ConfigProperties` class holding all parameters:

```
public void configHandler(ConfigParameters configParams = null)
{
    configParams = configParams ?? new ConfigParameters();

    if (configParams.Panel != null)
    {
        configParams.Panel.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.Active);
    }


    if (Convert.ToBoolean(configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.Active))
    {
        Config = true;

        if (configParams.Control != null)
        {
            configParams.Control.CssClass = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.CssClass) ? configParams.Control.CssClass : configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.CssClass;
            configParams.Control.ToolTip = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.ToolTip) ? configParams.Control.ToolTip : configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.ToolTip;
            configParams.Control.CssClass = MandatoryHandler(configParams.Control.CssClass, configParams.RequiredFieldValidator.Enabled);
        }

        if (configParams.RequiredFieldValidator != null)
        {
            configParams.RequiredFieldValidator.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.Mandatory);
            configParams.RequiredFieldValidator.ErrorMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.ErrorMessage) ? configParams.RequiredFieldValidator.ErrorMessage : configParams.SchemeConfigurationItem.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can configure each parameter separately without having to set other parameters explicitly to null:

```
configHandler(new ConfigParameters 
{
    SchemeConfigurationItem = ..., 
    Control = someCheckBoxList 
});
```

and the parameters are:

```
public class ConfigParameters
{
    public SchemeConfigurationItem SchemeConfigurationItem { get; set; }
    public IStyleable Control { get; set; }
    public bool Config { get; set; }
    public RequiredFieldValidator RequiredFieldValidator { get; set; }
    public Panel Panel { get; set; }
}
```